# How to use ConcatArrays in Spring Data MongoDB

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have the following JS code:

```
$concatArrays: [
              "$some.path",
              [
                {
                  "foo": "baz",
                  "x": 5
                }
              ]
            ]
```

How do I do the same with [ArrayOperators.ConcatArrays](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/ArrayOperators.ConcatArrays.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toy can use like following. You can pass the aggregation expresion or reference field name in `concat()`. So what you can do is, you can add the new array before `concat()` like

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      secondArray: [
        { "foo": "baz", "x": 5 }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      combined: {
        "$concatArrays": [ "$path", "$secondArray" ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KkXdLOo5aJZ)**

```
ArrayOperators.ConcatArrays concatArrays = ArrayOperators.ConcatArrays
.arrayOf("path")
.concat("secondArray");
```

Comment: What's `THE_SECOND_ARRAY`? A string representation of it? Can you demonstrate it with the array I supplied?

Comment: Have you hard coded the `foo` array inside `$concatArray`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the array field is defined as follows in a document:

```
{
        "_id": ObjectId("60bdc6b228acee4a5a6e1736"),
        "some" : {
                "path" : [
                        {
                                "foo" : "bar",
                                "x" : 99
                        }
                ]
        },
}
```

The following Spring Data MongoDB code returns the `result`- an array with two elements. The array field `"some.path"` and the input array `myArr` are concatenated using the `ArrayOperators.ConcatArrays` API.

```
String json = "{ 'foo': 'baz', 'x': 5 }";
Document doc = Document.parse(json);
List<Document> myArr = Arrays.asList(doc);

MongoOperations mongoOps = new MongoTemplate(MongoClients.create(), "testDB");
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
    addFields()
        .addFieldWithValue("myArr", myArr)
        .build(),
    addFields()
       .addField("result").withValue(ConcatArrays.arrayOf("$some.path").concat("$myArr"))
       .build()
);
        
AggregationResults<Document> results = mongoOps.aggregate(agg, "testColl", Document.class);
```